# Command-line image converter\resizer

Tags: imagemagick, image-resizing, graphicsmagick, image-conversion

I'm looking for a command-line image converter/resizer.

What i need to do is convert bitmap and tiff files into png files as well as creating a thumbnail. The images are relatively large. The largest is approximately 13,000 x 10,000 pixels and around 200mb.

I've tried ImageMagick. It used too much memory, was too slow, and couldn't handle the largest files without using disc cache making it unbearably slow.

Currently I'm using GraphicsMagick which uses less memory and can handle the larger files, but it is still a little slow. Around 15s per image.

Are there any other programs out there that could maybe offer a little better performance?

Comment: From what I understand Graphics magick is faster as it is only 8 bit. You could try installing an 8 bit version of Imagemagick which may open up more options?

Comment: @Bonzo GraphicsMagick is normally 16-bit, too, but like ImageMagick it is available in Q8, Q16, and other versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/). It's a streaming image processing library, so it's able to read the input, process, and write the output as a single pipeline, with no separate loading phase and no temporary files. It's got a fancy threaded IO system too, so [performance is good and memory use is low](https://github.com/libvips/libvips/wiki/Speed-and-memory-use).

I timed it on this machine (imac with ImageMagick 6.9.6-3 Q16, gm 1.3.25, vips 8.4.2):

```
$ vips black test.tif 13000 10000 --bands 3
$ ls -l test.tif
-rw-r--r--  1 john  staff  390000854 22 Nov 09:43 test.tif
```

So that's a 13000 x 10000 3-band, 8 bit uncompressed TIFF. With [vipsthumbnail](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/Using-vipsthumbnail.md.html), the image shrinker that comes with vips, I see:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -l vipsthumbnail test.tif -s 128x128 -o small.png
    0.54 real         0.42 user         0.11 sys
77635584  maximum resident set size
```

I ran three times and picked the fastest, so that should just be a test of `vipsthumbnail` and not my disk system. That's 0.54s real time, 77MB of peak memory.

With `convert` I see:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -l convert test.tif -resize 128x128 small.png
    4.87 real         4.28 user         0.55 sys
1432182784  maximum resident set size
```

Again, fastest of three runs, 4.87s real time, 1.4gb memory. GraphicsMagick is a little faster, I see:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -l gm convert test.tif -resize 128x128 small.png
    3.95 real         3.41 user         0.51 sys
1264369664  maximum resident set size
```

So 3.95s real, 1.2gb peak memory.

So on this test, libvips is 7x faster and uses 15x less memory than graphicsmagick.

libvips is a standard part of most linuxes, it's in homebrew and macports, and there are 64-bit windows binaries on the vips website.

Comment: Nice answer - I hope the OP accepts it. Btw, you can measure the peak resident set with `/usr/bin/time -l convert ...`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried libvips, but it took around 5x longer than GraphicsMagic, with roughly the same memory usage.

Comment: That's very strange. I updated my answer with gm timings too and `time -l` as @MarkSetchell suggested (thanks! I always forget macOs can do that). vips is 7x faster than GM and needs 15x less memory on this machine. What platform are you using, how did you test it, what command did you run, what image did you use?

Comment: I'm running it on windows 7. The image is 7000x10000 pixels tif file. the commands GM: "convert a.tif -thumbnail 1000 a.png" and for "vips a.tif -s 1000 -o a.png". GM takes 0.9s and vips takes 2.7s both with 380m memory

Comment: I tried on a win7 machine here -- with this vips http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/supported/current/win32/vips-dev-w64-web-8.4.4.zip a 7000 x 10000 tiff takes 0.47s. I couldn't time GM unfortunately as I don't have admin access.

Comment: I wouldn't use `-thumbnail`, it's very low quality, you'll get an image that's soft and also has aliasing problems. `vipsthumbnail` is doing the equivalent of `-resize`. Also, PNG write is very slow, so for a 1000 x 1000 pixel output you are seeing a lot of PNG write time. I'd try a smaller output image, or perhaps tiff output.

Comment: I did some more testing and using the image you used i do get the same memory usage and time. Unfortunately the images i'm converting have some kind of compression that is making it use so much memory and time.

Comment: That's a shame. Try using `tiffinfo` on one of your images, it'll print a detailed description of the structure of the file, including any compression type. You might have plane-separated data, libvips does not have a fast path for that data type.

Answer (score 0):

With either ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick you can speed up PNG encoding by using a lower "-quality" instead of accepting the default quality==75.  This will trade compression performance (file size) for speed.  Try `-quality 40` for line art, or `-quality 41` for photos.  Here are some results for a JPEG out of my camera, using ImageMagick-7.0.3-8 built with libpng-1.2.54:

```
glenn.rp> time magick D*88.JPG d88-q75.png
real    0m13.494s user  0m11.252s sys   0m2.060s
glenn.rp> time magick -quality 41 D*88.JPG d88-q41.png
real    0m7.377s user   0m4.728s sys    0m1.908s
glenn.rp> time magick -quality 40 D*88.JPG d88-q40.png
real    0m3.842s user   0m3.200s sys    0m0.584s
glenn.rp> ls -lt d88*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 glennrp glennrp 24352041 Nov 29 15:45 d88-q40.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 glennrp glennrp 17072518 Nov 29 15:45 d88-q41.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 glennrp glennrp 15788794 Nov 29 15:44 d88-q75.png
```